# MYSQL: split string on multiple criteria

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, split

I have a string with multiple delimiting function. But I need to retrieve a specific set in mysql.
Example:

```
/indoor-unit-for-split-acs-carrier-EL.AI.CA.468725/
/solar-inverters-su-kam-SO.SO.SO1.347598/
```

Then desired output is `EL.AI.CA.468725,SO.SO.SO1.347598` (only this part contain dots in that particular string)

Comment: This is not a code writing service. What did you try so far? Post your code! What happened when you ran it? What did you expect to happen instead? What specifically are you having problems with?

Comment: `SUBSTRING_index(..., -1)`

Comment: Robert i understand it is not a code writing engine. Just that i am new to stackflow community. I just did a simple post and if you help me out it would be great

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regular expression:

```
([A-Z.0-9]+)
```

See example here: https://regex101.com/r/4KK0zj/2

Answer (score 0):

**Test Data:**

```
CREATE TABLE TestDataTable
    (`id` int, `breadcrump` varchar(99))
;

insert into TestDataTable set breadcrump='/indoor-unit-for-split-acs-carrier-EL.AI.CA.468725/';
insert into TestDataTable set breadcrump='/solar-inverters-su-kam-SO.SO.SO1.347598/';
```

**Sample Query:**

```
select breadcrump
, replace( substring( breadcrump, (LENGTH(breadcrump) - LOCATE('-', REVERSE(breadcrump))+2)), '/','') as desiredOutPut
from TestDataTable;
```

**Sql Fiddle to test output:**

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cd69ac/2